# Multiple users accessing a same ipynb

Tags: permissions, ipython

I just set up a IPython (0.13.1) Notebook server in order to use it during my introductory course on Python. The server is protected with password and is currently up and running.

Now, I need my students (about 15 people) to access the same ipynb document at the same time, play around with it and eventualy modify the code examples, while making sure anyone overwrites the uploaded version of the ipynb file.

How can I set this up?

Answer (score 2):

First, take a look on [teaching with ipython notebook](http://ivory.idyll.org/blog/teaching-with-ipynb-2.html). Try to list what type of applications you want to run on this. On the other hand, it possible to use some cloud computing resources, for example on Heroku.